# boost::interprocess fastest way to update array

Tags: c++, windows, memory, boost, shared

I currently have a 1028*32 byte array of structures in shared memory using boost::interprocess.  Each of these contains location and drawing information from players in a game that I am scraping from a DLL to be drawn in a remote overlay.  My basic mechanism of controlling reading and writing is a bool at the beginning of the shared memory object that each process toggles on and off.  This method works, and I can get information from each of the players ingame, but unfortunately this method is really slow.  Is there any way to transfer this information quicker?  If at all possible, I would like to have it so that I can call my drawing function once a particular member of the array gets updated (say member 0 gets updated, before my scraper dll updates the next member, start drawing the info of member 0, then continue).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could a have a flag per member and continuously process the array and check for newly set flags. If you need more event style notifications then you could have a [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) for each individual member and signal it once it got updated. I'm not sure how the performance will be affected by having a 1000 monitors though.